# Как установить omnisharp для VS CODE?

Tags: c#, linux, visual-studio, archlinux

Установил VS Code на arch linux. При попытке скомпилировать простейший hellowolrd получил ответ:

> Please set up the launch configuration file to debug your application.

Хотел поставить omnisharp, но не разобрался какой из пакетов в их репозитории устанавливать для VS Code и как потом его подключить.

Главная задача - запустить VS Code и иметь возможность работать с C# в нем.

Comment: У вас установлен моно? Если установлен, то убедитесь, что у вас последняя версия.

Comment: Mono стоит актуальный. Mono JIT compiler version 4.2.1 (Stable 4.2.1.102/6dd2d0d Sun Nov 29 17:03:57 UTC 2015)

Comment: Вы пытаетесь сделать helloy world asp mvc приложение?

Comment: using System;

namespace mmNameSpace
{
    class Testing
    {
        static void Main()
        {

            Console.WriteLine("Hello");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}

Comment: не важно - любое простейшее консольное приложение, лишь бы скомпилировалось. Проблема в том, что список дебаггеров пуст и я не понимаю как добавить дебаггер для C#

Answer (score 1):

Без соответствующих плагинов вы не построите даже простого консольного приложения, по тому что без них VCS чуть больше чем текстовый редактор.

Рекомендую прочитать [эту](http://habrahabr.ru/company/microsoft/blog/262523/) статью. Там неплохой обзор и приведены ссылки на разные плагины.

[Тут](http://michaelcrump.net/creating-and-debugging-console-apps-with-vscode/) вы можете найти инструкцию по созданию консольного проложения.

Comment: Статья отличная и я е прочитал перед началом работы с Code, но где найти плагины для базового C#? Это asp.net?
Я так предположил, что удобнее всего мне было бы использовать omnisharp, 
он оффициально заявлен MS как поддерживаемый. Но в обилии их пакетов на репозитории я не смог найти нужный под VS CODE

Comment: По части подключения mono - он, как я описывал выше установлен. MS рекомендует (здесь: https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/editor/debugging)
If you want to attach the VS Code debugger to a Mono program, pass these additional arguments to the Mono runtime:
mono --debug --debugger-agent=transport=dt_socket,server=y,address=127.0.0.1:55555 Program.exe

Но непонятно что это за Program.exe. Это Скомпилированная мной программа? Но как я ее получу, если я не могу ничего
скомпилировать. Какой порт прописывать в launch.json тоже не понятно.

Comment: @Dubomire там же статья начинается со слов, установите ASP.NET5 :)