# VSCode нету подсветки синтаксиса C# ubuntu

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Пытаюсь разобраться с средой для C# разработки на Linux. Первое, что нашел так это VSCode. Решил затестить. C++, JavaScript, HTML, CSS файлы открываются отлично. С# файлы вообще не распознает. Тоисть подсветки нету совсем, про автодополнение и т.д. вообще молчу. Толи я чего то не понимаю, толи надо поставить какой-то плагин или пошаманить где-то. Если кто знает как исправить, подскажите!

Comment: https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/languages/csharp Пользуйтесь :)

Comment: Cпасибо. Плохо только, что на английском, тяжело разобраться.

Comment: Ну, это как раз способ его подтянуть. В любом случае без английского очень трудно в мире разработки.

Comment: А ещё тогда вопрос, если работаете может. Какой компилятор используете для C# на linux?

Comment: Нашел еще: 
https://habrahabr.ru/company/microsoft/blog/262523/   и   http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/474485/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-omnisharp-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-vs-code

Comment: нет, не работаю. Но судя по комментариям в ссылке выше и по статье на хабре - компилятор это mono.

Comment: по статье с хабра и ставил. Спасибо. Сейчас просмотрю вторую ссылку.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В общем нашел ответ. Заходим в VSCode. Жмем F1. Появится консоль студии. Extentions. Появится такое окошко.Выбираем первый вариант, и далее ищем

> C# for Visual Studio Code

Кликаем на данный пункт и ждем пока установится. Тут же можно установить и дебагер от mono. Перезагружаем студию и всё работает.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Год прошёл, ну не важно.

Может быть, достаточно было сменить "языковой режим"?!
(рядом со смайлом нижний правый угол, название определяемого типа файла по расширению). 
При открытом проблемном файле, покажет список с чем ассоциировать.

Настройки хранятся в подпапке `.vscode`, в текущей папке 
и в каталоге пользователя.

Если *Windows*, посмотреть `SET USERPROFILE`, в командной строке.